# Preprocessing in scikit learn - single sample - Depreciation warning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deprecation-warning

On a fresh installation of Anaconda under Ubuntu... I am preprocessing my data in various ways prior to a classification task using Scikit-Learn.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(train)
train = scaler.transform(train)    
test = scaler.transform(test)
```

This all works fine but if I have a new sample (temp below) that I want to classify (and thus I want to preprocess in the same way then I get

```
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,....................,7]
temp = scaler.transform(temp)
```

Then I get a deprecation warning...

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 
and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using 
X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1)
if it contains a single sample.
```

So the question is how should I be rescaling a single sample like this?

I suppose an alternative (not very good one) would be...

```
temp = [temp, temp]
temp = scaler.transform(temp)
temp = temp[0]
```

But I'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: Well... you just answered yourself. It's in the warning: `Reshape your data either using 
X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.` If your data is not a numpy array then use np.array(data) first.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just listen to what the warning is telling you:

> Reshape your data either X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature/column
>       and X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

For your example type(if you have more than one feature/column):

```
temp = temp.reshape(1,-1)
```

For one feature/column:

```
temp = temp.reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: I don't understand what do they mean by a single sample. X.shape returns (891, 158) . Any of the 2 solutions they propose give an error but I still get that warning if I don't reshape it.

Comment: Dont reshape X! its about y (target) !! y obviously has only one column. Had the same problem some days ago. Cost me an hour trying to reshape X ;-)

Comment: So... I wonder how many projects will break the day this finally becomes an error.

Comment: except that doing as it says (or supplying any valid input whatseover, as far as I can tell) does not make the warning go away.

Comment: I appreciated seeing this response. I received the similar error, but being new to python and numpy, the solution wasn't obvious.

Comment: It's kind of sad that the sklearn documentation doesn't give any explanation for this

Comment: predict a single sample with one feature:
>>> X_new = np.array([13]).reshape(-1, 1)
>>> model.predict(X_new)

Answer (score 34):

Well, it actually looks like the warning is telling you what to do.

As part of [`sklearn.pipeline` stages' uniform interfaces](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), as a rule of thumb:

- when you see `X`, it should be an `np.array` with two dimensions
- when you see `y`, it should be an `np.array` with a single dimension.

Here, therefore, you should consider the following:

```
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,....................,7]
# This makes it into a 2d array
temp = np.array(temp).reshape((len(temp), 1))
temp = scaler.transform(temp)
```

Comment: What is 'np' object?

Comment: @Tajchert Sorry about that - `import numpy as np`.

Comment: thanks :) Just starting Python so that wan't obvious

Comment: `#This makes it into a 2d array`
    `temp =  [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,....................,7]  #an instance`
    `temp = np.array(temp).reshape((1, -1))`
    `print(model.predict(temp))`

Comment: Does it mean that sklearn decided to discourage python native lists? Is there still a way to not use numpy?

Comment: You can simplify the second command by giving an unknown dimension like: temp = np.array(temp).reshape((-1, 1))

Answer (score 9):

This might help

```
temp = ([[1,2,3,4,5,6,.....,7]])
```

Answer (score 3):

`.values.reshape(-1,1)` will be accepted without alerts/warnings

`.reshape(-1,1)` will be accepted, but with deprecation war

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and got the same deprecation warning. I was using a numpy array of [23, 276] when I got the message. I tried reshaping it as per the warning and end up in nowhere. Then I select each row from the numpy array (as I was iterating over it anyway) and assigned it to a list variable. It worked then without any warning.

```
array = []
array.append(temp[0])
```

Then you can use the python list object (here 'array') as an input to sk-learn functions. Not the most efficient solution, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always, reshape like:

```
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7]

temp = temp.reshape(len(temp), 1)
```

Because, the major issue is when your, temp.shape is:
(8,)

and you need 
(8,1)

Answer (score 0):

-1 is the unknown dimension of the array. Read more about "newshape" parameters on [numpy.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape) documentation -

```
# X is a 1-d ndarray

# If we want a COLUMN vector (many/one/unknown samples, 1 feature)
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

# you want a ROW vector (one sample, many features/one/unknown)
X = X.reshape(1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = df[['x_1']] 
X_n = X.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df['target']  
y_n = y.values
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_n, y)

y_pred = pd.Series(model.predict(X_n), index=X.index)
```

Comment: When answering such an old question, with a highly upvoted accepted answer, please take the time to explain what your new answer is adding to the topic. Please edit your answer is explain how your answer is better/new/improved.