# Create submodels with pandas groupby and locate each model with test data

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, prediction

I have a pandas dataframe in which values in a column are used as the group-by basis to create submodels.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

data = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], "Score": [90, 80, 90, 92, 87, 80], "Age": [10, 12, 14, 9, 11, 12], "Training": [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]})
```

`"Name"` is used as the basis to create submodel for each individual. I want o use variable `"Age"` and `"Training"` to predict `"Score"` of one individual `"Name"` (i.e `"A"` and `"B"` in this case). That is, if I have `"A"` and know the `"Age"` and `"Training"` of `"A"`, I would love to use `"A"`, `"Age"`, `"Training"` to predict `"Score"`. However, `"A"` should be used to access to the model that `"A"` belongs to other than other model.

```
grouped_df = data.groupby(['Name'])
for key, item in grouped_df:
    Score = grouped_df['Score']
    Y = grouped_df['Age', 'Training']
    Score_item = Score.get_group(key)
    Y_item = Y.get_group(key)
    model = Ridge(alpha = 1.2)
    modelfit = model.fit(Y_item, Score_item)
    modelpred = model.predict(Y_item)
    modelscore = model.score(Y_item, Score_item)
    print modelscore
```

Up to here, I have built simple Ridge models to sub-groups `A` and `B`.

My question is, with test data as below:

```
test_data = [u"A, 13, 0", u"B, 12, 1", u"A 10, 0"] ##each element, respectively, represents `Name`, `Age` and `Training`
```

How to feed the data to the prediction models?
I have

```
line = test_data
Name = [line[i].split()[0] for i in range(len(line))]
Age = [line[i].split()[1] for i in range(len(line))]
Training = [line[i].split()[2] for i in range(len(line))]
Y = pd.DataFrame({"Name": Name, "Age": Age, "Training": Training})
```

This gives me the pandas dataframe of the test data. However, I am not sure how to proceed further to feed the test data to the model. I highly appreciate your help. Thank you!!

**UPDATE**

After I adopted the code of Parfait, the code looks better now. Here I did not, however, create another pandas dataframe of the testdata (as I am not sure how to deal with row in there). Instead, I feed in the test values by spliting strings. I obtained an error as indicated below. I searched and found a post here [Preprocessing in scikit learn - single sample - Depreciation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082140/preprocessing-in-scikit-learn-single-sample-depreciation-warning) which is related. However, I tried to reshape the test data but it is on the list form so it does not have the attribute of reshap. I think I misunderstand. I highly appreciate if you can let me know how to fix this error. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], "Score": [90, 80, 90, 92, 87, 80], "Age": [10, 12, 14, 9, 11, 12], "Training": [0, 1, 2, 0,$


modeldict = {}                                           # INITIALIZE DICT
grouped_df = data.groupby(['Name'])

for key, item in grouped_df:
    Score = grouped_df['Score']
    Y = grouped_df['Age', 'Training']
    Score_item = Score.get_group(key)
    Y_item = Y.get_group(key)
    model = Ridge(alpha = 1.2)
    modelfit = model.fit(Y_item, Score_item)
    modelpred = model.predict(Y_item)
    modelscore = model.score(Y_item, Score_item)
    modeldict[key] = modelfit                            # SAVE EACH FITTED MODEL TO DICT


line = [u"A, 13, 0", u"B, 12, 1", u"A, 10, 0"]
Name = [line[i].split(",")[0] for i in range(len(line))]
Age = [line[i].split(",")[1] for i in range(len(line))]
Training = [line[i].split(",")[2] for i in range(len(line))]


for i in range(len(line)):
Name = line[i].split(",")[0]
Age = line[i].split(",")[1]
Training = line[i].split(",")[2]
model = modeldict[Name]
ip = [float(Age), float(Training)]
score = model.predict(ip)

print score
```

**ERROR**

```
/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. DeprecationWarning)
86.6666666667
/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.DeprecationWarning)
83.5320600273
/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.DeprecationWarning)
86.6666666667
/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.DeprecationWarning)
[ 86.66666667]
/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.DeprecationWarning)
[ 83.53206003]
/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. DeprecationWarning)
[ 86.66666667]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving submodels in a dictionary with *Name* as the key and then run a [pandas.DataFrame.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to run operations on each row aligning row's *Name* to corresponding model.

**NOTE:** Below is untested code but hopefully gives a general idea to which you can adjust accordingly. The main issue might be the `model.predict()` input and output in the defined function, `runModel`, used in the `apply()`. A numpy matrix to of *Age* and *Training* values are used in `model.predict()` which hopefully returns a numpy equal to sample size (i.e., each row). See [Ridge model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html):

```
modeldict = {}                                           # INITIALIZE DICT
grouped_df = data.groupby(['Name'])

for key, item in grouped_df:
    Score = grouped_df['Score']
    Y = grouped_df['Age', 'Training']
    Score_item = Score.get_group(key)
    Y_item = Y.get_group(key)
    model = Ridge(alpha = 1.2)
    modelfit = model.fit(Y_item, Score_item)
    modelpred = model.predict(Y_item)
    modelscore = model.score(Y_item, Score_item)
    print modelscore

    modeldict[key] = modelfit                            # SAVE EACH FITTED MODEL TO DICT

line = [u"A, 13, 0", u"B, 12, 1", u"A 10, 0"] 
Name = [line[i].split()[0] for i in range(len(line))]
Age = [line[i].split()[1] for i in range(len(line))]
Training = [line[i].split()[2] for i in range(len(line))]

testdata = pd.DataFrame({"Name": Name, "Age": Age, "Training": Training})

def runModel(row):
    # LOCATE MODEL BY NAME KEY 
    model = modeldict[row['Name']]
    # PREDICT VALUES
    score = model.predict(np.matrix([row['Age'], row['Training']])
    # RETURN SCALAR FROM score ARRAY 
    return(score[0])    

testdata['predictedScore'] = testdata.apply(runModel, axis=1)
```