# Accuracy of preprocessing single sample

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, knn

I've been working to predict samples with the sklearn implementation of KNN.

So far i've been training my classifier with a sample of my dataset, and then testing it with another distinct sample of the dataset and appearing to see an accuracy of around 98%.

However, when attempting to predict a single sample the predictions are all over the place even when using samples the model has been trained on. The only guess i have is that there is a problem when preprocessing the entire dataset with preprocessing.scale versus preprocessing a single sample with the same technique.

I've read [Preprocessing in scikit learn - single sample - Depreciation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082140/preprocessing-in-scikit-learn-single-sample-depreciation-warning) and am wondering if there is a correct way to preprocess a single sample.

EDIT: Code for preprocessing shown below
For the whole dataset:

```
self.trainData = preprocessing.scale(self.trainData)
```

For a single sample, where log is of the same form as samples in traindata.

`log = preprocessing.scale(log)`

Comment: Show the code, how are you processing the single sample. You should use the same scales that were used in training. If you call `scale()` on individual sample, it would give wrong results.

Comment: I've added code, if i get incorrect results when using scale() on a single sample, how would i preprocess a single sample correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) which is a wrapper over the `scale` function as [described here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-scaler). This wrapper stores the mean and standard deviation learned from the training data and then uses this information to scale the other data.

Example usage:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

trainData = scaler.fit_transform(trainData)
# I have used reshape because of single sample. In other cases, its not needed
log = scaler.transform(np.reshape(log, (1,-1)))
```

`fit_transform()` is just a shortcut for first calling `fit()` and then `transform()`.

`fit()` method does not return anything. It just analyses the data to learn the mean and standard_deviation. `transform()` will use the learnt mean and std to scale the data and returns the new data.

You should only call `fit()` or `fit_transform()` on the training data,never on anything else. For transforming the test or new data, always use `transform()`.

Comment: Awesome, that solves the issue, and ended up improving the accuracy of the model a bit as well.