# Why np.zeros(3) and np.zeros((3,1)) are of different dimensions in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimension

I'm trying to generate N data points for three random variables that are jointly normal in python.
If I use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pandas
import sys
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
from pandas import *
N=100
Sigma=np.identity(3)
Mu=np.zeros((3,1))
Z=np.random.multivariate_normal(Mu, Sigma, N)
```

I got the following error message:

```
in <module>
    Z=np.random.multivariate_normal(Mu, Sigma, N)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4067, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.multivariate_normal
ValueError: mean must be 1 dimensional
```

This means that the dimension of `np.zeros((3,1))` is not `1`. After changing the line `Mu=np.zeros((3,1))` to `Mu=np.zeros(3)`, it works. This implies that `np.zeros(3)` is `1` dimensional.

As `np.zeros(3)` and `np.zeros((3,1))` are both an array of three zeros, I guess naturally both should be 1 dimensional. Using `Mu.ndim` in each case, I found that the dimension of `np.zeros(3)` is one and the dimension of `np.zeros((3,1))` is two. My question is:

*Why does Python make a distinction between `np.zeros((3,1))` and `np.zeros(3)` regarding their dimensions (why is this distinction useful)?*

Comment: Is a vector with 3 scalars and a 3x1 matrix a different thing? That's the difference between 1d and 2d.

Comment: @CJR Thanks! In some other languages, such as MATLAB, a vector with 3 scalars and a 3x1 matrix  are the same thing. In linear algebra, they are also the same thing. Are they treated as different things in computer science?

Comment: Linear algebra considers a vector in 3-space the same as an overdetermined system of equations in 1-space?

Comment: @CJR Those two things are of course different in linear algebra. What I was saying is that in linear algebra, we don't distinguish between a vector with 3 coordinates and a 3x1 matrix.  For example, $[0 0 0]^\top$ in linear algebra is both a 3-dimensional vector and a 3x1 matrix.

Comment: In MATLAB everything is 2d.  Size of a 'scalar' is (1,1).  In `numpy` any dimension 0-32 is possible.  `np.zeros((1,1,3,1)` is a 4d with 3 elements.  Python has scalars and lists.  Lists are 1d, though they may be nested.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! This is very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal for them to have different dimensions. The first one only has 1 array made of 3 zeros and the second one has 3 arrays each one made of 1 zero.

If you print `Mu[0]` in your example, you will get a list `[0.]` while if you print `Mu[0]` after using `np.zeros(3)` to define it, you will get `0.0`

I can think of cases where this is distinction is useful especially when working with features in machine learning. If I have a sequence of features of size 1, I would want to use a dimension [n,1] and not [n] because that helps the model (let's say LSTM) make a difference between the sequence size and the feature size.

Comment: YES. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38321679/2640045

Comment: An array with multiple dimensions is not multiple arrays. It's still a single memory contiguous C array on the backend.

Comment: @CJR Thanks for the clarification. You're right because numpy allocates a continuous array in the memory. I just used that to explain the difference in an easier way.